# Why do I get the new data but node.js does not send the data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I use this code to get the new insertion in a mongo database and send it to the html file:

```
mongo.MongoClient.connect (uristring, function (err, db) { 
        db.collection ("speed", function (err,collection) {
        collection.isCapped(function (err, capped) { 
        if (!capped) {
        console.log (collection.collectionName + " is not a capped collection");
        }
        else
        {
          var cursorOptions = {
          tailable: true,
          awaitdata: true,
          numberOfRetries: -1
        };
        var stream = collection.find({},{value:1,_id:0},cursorOptions).sort({$natural: -1}).stream();

        stream.on('data', function(document) {
          io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
          socket.emit('message', {'message': document});
        });
        });
        }
        });
    });
});
```

on the client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('/');
  var myValue = [];
  socket.on('message',function(data){
    console.log(data);
    myValue.push(data.message.value);
```

It works fine when I read the data at first but when I insert the new data when server is running,the data shows in the server but does not send to the client.

Comment: Well, do you have a websocket connection open on client side listening on `message`?

Comment: yes..

var socket = io.connect('/');
  var myValue = [];
  socket.on('message',function(data){
    console.log(data);
    myValue.push(data.message.value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 stream.on('data', function(document) {
            socket.emit('message', {'message': document});
          io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
          socket.emit('message', {'message': document});
        });
        });
```

at your first socket.emit(), which socket are you referring?
 Removing your first socket.emit will solve the problem.

```
stream.on('data', function(document) {
          io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
          socket.emit('message', {'message': document});
        });
        });
```

Or changing your code as following should also work fine.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
              stream.on('data', function(document) {
                    socket.emit('message', {'message': document});
                    });
                });
```

Comment: do you guarantee that your have a successful connection between socket.io server and socket.io client? If yes, then above should work.